# Apache does not start at boot on OpenSUSE

Tags: linux, apache2, system-administration, apache, opensuse

I want Apache2 to start att boot. This is what I have

`ls -l` in

```
/etc/init.d/rc5.d
```

lists, among a lot of other things, this:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 18 10:35 S12apache2 -> ../apache2
```

In `/etc/init.d/` 'apache2' is indeed located. And `ls -l` on apache2 lists

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 root root 10635 Feb 18 22:09 apache2
```

`/sbin/chkconfig -a apache2` prints

```
apache2                   0:off  1:off  2:off  3:on   4:off  5:on   6:off
```

Shouldn't this be necessary in order for Apache to start at boot?

I usually start manually using `sudo /usr/sbin/rcapache2 restart`

/Niklas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chmod 755 /etc/init.d/apache2` fixed it

Comment: AS of opensuse 12.3 this command helped me:

```ln -s /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service /usr/lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/apache2.service```

Comment: FYI, that LN command is indirectly invoked by the cleaner solution posted by @AndreaAjek.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that starting with openSUSE 12 systemd is a replacement for the popular SysV init daemon. Systemd is fully compatible with SysV init (by supporting init scripts). One of the main advantages of systemd is the fact that it considerably speeds up boot time by aggressively paralleling service starts.

Command for permanently enabling apache2 service:

```
# systemctl enable apache2.service
```

Note: when enabling a service on the command line, it's not started automatically. It's scheduled to be started with the next system start-up or runlevel/target change. In order to immediately start a service, explicitly run `systemctl start service_name.service` (i.e. `systemctl start apache2.service`).

(More info about the systemd daemon: https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_122/opensuse-reference/cha.systemd.html)